# INSERT statement conflicted with foreign key constraint - SQL Server/Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I get this error in my .NET Core 3.1 app:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_DiaryDiaryEntry". The conflict occurred in database "xxxxxx", table "dbo.Diaries", column 'Id'.

I can't see anything wrong with the tables themselves.

```
    public partial class Diaries
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string CoverImage { get; set; }
        public short Year { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long ChildId { get; set; }

        public Children Child { get; set; }
        public ICollection<DiaryEntries> DiaryEntries { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DiaryEntries
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public long DiaryId { get; set; }

        public Diaries Diary { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Images> Images { get; set; }
    }
```

My code? Probably an entirely different matter.

This is the code that generates the error.

```
[HttpPost("CreateYear/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateYearOfEntries([FromRoute] int id)
{
        // The id is the ID of an existing diary
        // Make sure the diary does exist first and that it belongs to the current logged-in user
        var diary = _diaryRepository.Find(id);

        if (diary == null) return NotFound();

        var year = diary.Result.Year;

        if (await _diaryEntryRepository.OwnerIsLoggedIn(LoggedInUser.ParentId, id))
        {
            var noOfDays = DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? 366 : 365;
            var i = 0;

            for (; i < noOfDays; i++)
            {
                var date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(i);
                var newDiaryEntry = new DiaryEntries()
                {
                    Content = " ",
                    Date = date,
                    DiaryId = diary.Id
                };

                await _diaryEntryRepository.Add(newDiaryEntry);
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        return NotFound();
}

public class DiaryEntryRepository : IDiaryEntryRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DiaryEntryRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<DiaryEntries> Add(DiaryEntries diaryEntry)
    {
        await _context.DiaryEntries.AddAsync(diaryEntry);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return diaryEntry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `DiaryId = diary.Id` whne you create the `new DiaryEntries()` why don't you try simply ... `DiaryId = id`?

Comment: An alternative to that would be to replace `DiaryId = diary.Id' with 'Diary = diary'. If neither of those two work, I would be reviewing the EF mapping to your database schema.

Comment: The DiaryId = id did it. I'm not too clear on whether I should use Diary = diary and how Core deals with relational data. If I was just to use DiaryId=id, is core clever enough to load up the linked DiaryEntries if I was to include them in a query that loads a Diary?

Comment: Use what work :) ... I have done both. EF should properly associate the FK if you assign the Object property or the Related Key value. Both method should allow you to query the linked Diary Entries. You should be able to validate that via a simple SQL query.